# Unable to install material ui in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

[ERROR Thrown by npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb0RP.png)

Here is my package.json

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsL6F.png)

Comment: Just delete the node_module folder and again install with npm install --clear-cache

Comment: It's better to add the error text to the question rather than a screenshot of the error in your console.